# Will Java garbage collector reclaim non-referenced object which contains reference to other objects

Tags: java, list, garbage-collection

This question arises when I am learning the **LinkedList** data structure. Assume every **Link** (or Node) is represented by an object which contains two fields, *data* & *next* points to the next link. If I want to delete a specific node, clearly I will update the previous Link's *next* field. But should I set deleted link's *next* field to null, so as to make sure it will be reclaimed by the garbage collector ?

If my description is not clear, I try to generalize (or simplify) my question. Suppose an object **a1** of class **A** which has a field, which references another object **a2** of the same class. If there is no reference to object **a1**, will it be eligible for garbage collector ? Or we must explicitly set reference field in **a1** to be ***null*** ? (don't care about object **a2**, there are other references to it besides the reference field in **a1**).

Answer (score 6):

Garbage collector ideally collect all objects, which are not reachable by program flow. Even if this object has references to everything in JVM.
Object becomes unreachable if all running threads of program don't contain any *direct* or *indirect* references to it.
Direct reference looks like this:

```
void main(String... args){
  Object a = new Object(); // <- from here main thread of program 
                           //    has reference to object `a`
  ...
}
```

Indirect reference looks like this:

```
void main(String... args){
   List b = new ArrayList();
   b.add(new Object()); // <- here you can't access object by typing `a`
   // as in previous example, but you can get access with `b.get(0);`
   // so that object can be accessed indirectly -> it is reachable.
}
```

It also handles properly cases of big isles of objects, which have references to each other, but none of which is reachable from program flow anymore.

```
MyClass a = new MyClass();
MyClass b = new MyClass();
a.field = b;
b.field = a;
// at this point a and b are reachable so they cannot be collected
b = null;
// at this point b's object is reachable indirectly through `a.field`
// so neither a nor b can be collected
a = null;
// at this point you cannot reach neither a nor b
// so a and b can be garbage collected, 
// despite the fact that a is referenced by b and vice versa
```

UPD: added examples, changed some words to make answer clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your object a1 can be collected even if its fields still reference other objects. You do not need to set its fields to null.

The garbage collector collects objects which are not *reachable*. An object can hold references to others and still be collected. An object may have references to it, from other non-reachable objects, and still be collected.

Answer (score 0):

All orphan objects are automatically eligible for garbage collection. And you do not need to explicitility set reference to null (however it's a good coding practice).

Answer (score 0):

When the garbage collector will run, it will see that now `a1` needs to be garbage collected as there are no longer references to it.

Also it will remove the reference field in `a1` pointing to object of `a2`

but still for `a2` (as you have mentioned for `a2` *there are other references to it besides the reference field in a1*) so it is not eligible for garbage collection, hence it remains.